# Pinescript calculate based on all bars within a session

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have this standard deviation calculation in Pinescript V5 and I want to be able to change the length input of it to be based on all bars within the RTH session instead of 20 which it is now:

> Standard deviation calculation
> length = input(20, title = "Length")
> mult = input(2.0, title = "Multiplier")
> stdDev = ta.stdev(Close, length)

I've tried creating a session input but do not know how to make the calculation based on all bars in the session and continuously change as more bars are created in the session

Answer (score -1):

You can use an array and push your source (`close`) as long as you are in the session. Then the size of the array would be your `length`.

**Note:** You need to clean your array once a new session starts.

The compiler probably will not like the fact that the `length` argument is not known at compile time. Therefore you might need to calculate the standard deviation yourself.

The calculation method is available so you could adapt.

```
isZero(val, eps) => math.abs(val) <= eps

SUM(fst, snd) =>
    EPS = 1e-10
    res = fst + snd
    if isZero(res, EPS)
        res := 0
    else
        if not isZero(res, 1e-4)
            res := res
        else
            15

pine_stdev(src, length) =>
    avg = ta.sma(src, length)
    sumOfSquareDeviations = 0.0
    for i = 0 to length - 1
        sum = SUM(src[i], -avg)
        sumOfSquareDeviations := sumOfSquareDeviations + sum * sum

    stdev = math.sqrt(sumOfSquareDeviations / length)
plot(pine_stdev(close, 5))
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I'm not sure I quite understand how to incorporate it into the script. Would you be able to provide an example of how I can do this? 

I'm trying to plot 2std deviation upper and lower bands on the session